# Copy and pasting data back into the Tab the assigned button was pressed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to create an app script and assign it to a button in a tab. This button will act as a means to fix the current sheet by going into another 'Fixer' sheet that is mostly identical. Then, repaste all the formulas from the fixer to the sheet where the button was activated.

The separation between the functional sheet and the fixer sheet is that the functional sheet has an app script that alters the Tab Name to a specific cell reference. This cell contains a person's name that also influences all the data within the sheet.

The functionality in the second paragraph is where I am getting stuck creating code. The nature of the tool is to be fluid to add and replace name references regularly. However, when I move out of the functional sheet, it maps to the tab name that will inherently change, making the code I have useless.

I need to find a way to make the data paste back into the active tab the button was pressed.

The below code is from the base I have been trying to manipulate.

```
function FixTab() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Fix Sheet'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:N').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PersonX'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Fix Sheet'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PersonX'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Fix Sheet\'!A:N').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E4:F4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('U4:V4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

Comment: Your code looks like it was originally developed as a macro.  You should learn how to develop code without the use of activate() and setActiveSpreadsheet, if for no other reason because most of us hate to even read it.

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper. You are correct. I have been using a Macro as my foundation and trying to learn by tailoring everything from that base. This has gotten me 95% of the way to developing a cool and sustainable build. I have tried a few adaptations from this base that have been unfruitful. I am finding it difficult to research a way to move the data dump back to a sheet that will likely have a different sheet name at the time the script is being run.

Comment: It may be sustainable to you but to me it's a huge mess.

Comment: Good stuff Coop

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I was able to get to a solution with the documentation combined with some trial and error. It was so much simpler than what I thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you need to spend some time learning the basics of JavaScript like how to declare a variable.

The following line is a variable declaration, it assigns the active sheet to the variable `sheet`.

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

The above should be added at the beginning of your function. Then replace

```
spreadsheet.getRange('U4:V4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

by

```
spreadsheet.getRange('U4:V4').copyTo(sheet.getRange('A1'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

where A1 should be the address of the top-left cell of the range where the copied range should be pasted.

Comment: Thanks, Ruben. I already came up with a solution I will post when I get time to articulate it effectively.

I will return to this and try it out for my learning. Thank again for your guidance!